# css3 transition not working properly in opera

Tags: css, opera, css-transitions

Opera supports css3 transition perfectly according various websites. When I first tried everything worked fine because I first tried the basic example of `width` transition. But when I tried transition with background color, In opera nothing happens on the name of transition. The code is working fine in chrome but not in opera. Also when I tried transition with other properties like `box-shadow`, `text-shadow` ,Opera gives the same result - nothing worked. Is opera only support width transition. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/C3GBF/14/), you can have a look over the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the recently released Opera 12, it appears to work fine with your example.

Comment: yeah! sorry somehow i have an old version